# Programming In General - Binary Search Algorithms

Tags: php, algorithm

Given an array $array of N numbers and a key $key, write the binary search algorithm in plain English. If $array contains $key, return the index of the $key; otherwise, return -1.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: Binary search algorithm code can be found at e.g. Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm.

Comment: Sounds like homework.. and there are so many examples on using PHP and creating binary search. Why ask the question here if you can google and help yourself?

Comment: I learn quicker this way, can you please help?

Comment: @user700070 Learn quicker what way? (By someone doing the work for you?) @Oli pointed you at a detailed description of what a binary search algorithm does and how it works - what more do you require?

Comment: No it helps me to visualize how to do it, I always learned by having others showing me previous code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't seem like I should give you the code here, but maybe this description can help?

1. Sort the list.
2. Let `i = length / 2`
3. Compare term at index `i` to your key.

   a. If they are equal, return the index.

   b. If key is greater than this term, repeat 3 (recurse) on upper half of list `i = (i + length) / 2`  (or `(i + top) / 2` depending how you implement)

   c. If key is less than this term, repeat 3 on lower half `i = i/2` or `(i + bottom)/2`

Stop recursion if/when the new `i` is the same as the old `i`.  This means you've exhausted the search.  Return -1

---

Be careful for off-by-one errors, which can make you exclude certain terms by mistake, or cause infinite recursion, but this is the general idea.  Pretty straightforward.

Think of it as playing 'Guess the number' for the numbers 1 through 100.  You take a guess, I tell you higher or lower.  You say 50, I say lower.  You say 25, I say higher.  You say 37...

Comment: no problem.  they're not idiots, i understand getting frustrated with questions like this.  still, i think theres ways to help without giving it away.  next time try searching first, im sure theres gotta be something similar or damn near identical to this already out there.  good luck

Comment: and as a small aside concerning efficiency.  check for equality last.  its the least likely case, so you'd do less unnecessary comparisons if you put the greater/less than cases first.

Comment: @user: Calling people "idiots" will not be conducive to you getting any help in the future.  @jon's answer is identical to anything you could read on the Wikipedia page, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is little late :) ,but take it anyway.This also show that recursive function works faster than in_array()

```
 function binarySearch($A,$value,$starting,$ending)
    {
       if($ending<$starting)
       {
          return -1;
       }
       $mid=intVal(($starting+$ending)/2);

       if($value===$A[$mid])
          {
              return $mid;
          }
       else if($value<$A[$mid])
          {
             $ending=$mid-1;
          }
       else if($value>$A[$mid])
          {
             $starting=$mid+1;
          }

       return binarySearch($A,$value,$starting,$ending);
    }

    for($i;$i<1000000;$i++){
       $arr[$i]=$i;
    }
    $value =99999;

    $msc=microtime(true);
    $pos = in_array($value,$arr);
    $msc=microtime(true)-$msc; 

    echo "Time taken for in_array() : ".round($msc*1000,3).' ms <br>';
    if($pos>0)
    echo $value .' found.';
    else
    echo $value .' not found';

    echo "<br><br>";
    $msc=microtime(true);
    $pos = binarySearch($arr,$value ,0,1000000);
    $msc=microtime(true)-$msc; 

    echo "Time taken for recursive function : ".round($msc*1000,3).' ms<br>';
    if($pos>=0)
    echo $value .' found.';
    else
    echo $value .' not found';
```

Ouput:

```
Time taken for in_array() : 5.165 ms 
99999 found.

Time taken for recursive function : 0.121 ms
99999 found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better non recursive solution.

```
function fast_in_array($elem, $array){
   $top = sizeof($array) -1;
   $bot = 0;

   while($top >= $bot)
   {
      $p = floor(($top + $bot) / 2);
      if ($array[$p] < $elem) $bot = $p + 1;
      elseif ($array[$p] > $elem) $top = $p - 1;
      else return TRUE;
   }

   return FALSE;
}
```